# Python: Import excel file using relative path

Tags: python, pandas, importerror, import-from-excel

I tried to import an excel file which is not within the same folder than the script. I need to get one folder above, then into another folder (B_folder) and there is file 2_file.xlsx

I tried:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'..\B_folder\2_file.xlsx')
```

and got:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '..\\B_folder\\2_file.xlsx'
```

also tried:

- foreslash instead of backslash
- without the 'r' before path

but I always get the error message above or this one:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '..\\B_folder\2_file.xlsx'
```

what is wrong?

Comment: Windows or Mac?

Comment: working with Windows

Comment: Try specifying the full path...

Comment: this works but I need the relative one cause I have to hand it in

Comment: Your file path must be wrong then.

Comment: Remember that the relative path is calculated with respect to the folder where your script runs.

Comment: checked that. the structure looks like this: one folder contains two folders, one with scripts and one with excel files (B_folder). So starting with the script location I go one folder up and then into B_folder. Is the coding I posted korrekt to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions. None of them did work but I found a solution.

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'./../B_folder/2_file.xlsx')
```

This works perfectly fine for me.

So if anybody faces the same problem, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the absolute path first:

```
import os.path
fullpath = os.path.abspath('..\B_folder\2_file.xlsx')
```

And use it to open the Excel file.

If the `\` do not work, you can use this syntax:

```
fullpath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..', 'B_folder', '2_file.xlsx'))
```

Comment: tried that. fullpath looks like this: `'C:\\Users\\B_folder\x02_file.xlsx'` but
`df = pd.read_excel(fullpath)` still does not work. even removed the number in front of the filename but it seems like this is not the problem