# Concatenating string and filepath adds extra backslash in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, operating-system, glob

This is almost embarrassingly simple, but I couldn't find a way around this at all. My code used to work just fine as well, and nothing fundamental has changed. Honestly, I can't see the mistake.

In the following code whenever I run a pd.read_excel, I get an extra backslash in my concatenation:

```
sports_data = [pd.read_excel(r'Data\NData' + str(season) + ".xlsx") for season in season_list]
```

All I want is the filepath beginning, to be tied to the season variable I set earlier in a list.

Thanks, and trust me that I checked high and wide for this!

I've tested the same with double slashes, as well as a raw string. None of them work as each time the backslashes are doubled. I've even separated the filepath, but it still doesn't work

The error I get is the following, each time:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Data\\NData2002-2003.xlsx'
```

If I attempt to run a double-backslash to get the line skip to be a simple backslash, it is still doubled:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Data\\\\NData2002-2003.xlsx'
```

Comment: Ok figured this out - it doesn't look to feasible to do this easily, so simply omitted the use of a directory as a part of the read_excel process. Moved all the data files to the .py folder, and it all works now as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is consistent with Python's normal behavior. Try it out in the REPL:

```py
>>> s = r'path\to\my\file'
>>> s
'path\\to\\my\\file'
>>> print(s)
path\to\my\file
```

A raw string literal still gets stored as a normal string internally, and backslashes still need to be escaped in Python when getting a filepath. Are you sure that the file exists? Double-check the filename and type to see that they match exactly.

Comment: Hey! That's fair, the behavior seems to work as expected. The file is in place, in the right folder. Named: NData2002-2003.xlsx. So the file in and of itself isn't problematic, that side I've checked quite a few times. Just trying to see how I can work around the double slash.

Comment: To be clear, you are running your Python script in some folder `FolderA`, and `FolderA` **also** contains a `Data` folder, which in turn contains `NData2002-2003.xlsx`?

Comment: Yes - the folder structure is correct, and the files are named accordingly. NData2002-2003.xlsx is there for sure, in the Data folder.

Comment: Thanks for the help Michael! I ended up just discarding the folder call in the read_excel part, and moved all the data files to the same folder with the py file. It works now, so looks like it just isn't too feasible to throw in the filepath. Will just use this for now. Thanks however for having a look!

Comment: No problem, I took a look through the source code but it doesn't seem to offer any clues. You can try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50251905), which suggests using forward slashes, as well as possibly two relative paths `./` and `../`. So maybe try `r'Data/NData' + str(season) + ".xlsx"` or `r'./Data/NData' + str(season) + ".xlsx"`. If either one works, feel free to update my answer, or let me know and I'll update it.

Comment: Fair, I actually did try that as well, but it didn't work. Feels like might be just best to go more basic.