# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read my excel file with pd.read_excel in python.
But ı am get this error message = FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I put my excel file same place with my python file.
[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb9yE.png)                     [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxi4l.png)

Comment: Please the image upload with built-in system of Stackoverflow.

Comment: Does it work if you use the full path?

Comment: ı tried this but ı thing ı did something wrong and not working.        pd.read_excel(C:\Users\selman\PycharmProjects\selman_learning\bisiklet_fiyatlari.xlsx) can you help me about this ?

Comment: @Matteo [Please do not encourage others to upload images in order to show common error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). We **only** want images for information that **cannot reasonably be communicated** in plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use full path this way to read the excel file. And also add `r` prefix before the file path so backslash will be treated as literal character

```
pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\selman\PycharmProjects\selman_learning\bisiklet_fiyatlari.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
path = 'absolute_path/records.xlsx' #eg. C:\\Projects\\readexcel\\file\\records.xlsx
df = pd.read_excel(path)
```

Do the above

Answer (score 0):

I think you can modify the code by writing it in this way:

```
pd.read_excel("./<file name>")
```

Comment: Why would you add dot (.) if you are giving full path?

Comment: no sorry try this : "./bisiklet_fiyatlari.xlsx", it would work

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put file object and not only the path of the file.
Try to use:

```
with open("<path to your file>", encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
     pandas.read_excel(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing the absolute path to the .xlsx file worked for me. For situations where you cannot anticipate what the absolute path will be, try the following:

```
import os.path

pd.read_excel(io=os.path.abspath('path\\to\\excel_file.xlsx'))
```

'path\to\excel_file.xlsx' should be the relative path to the .xlsx from the project root.

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50120018/9022913) to a similar question.